# How to read a JAR or EXE file on my FTP server without having the file on local?

Tags: jar, localhost, exe

I have a JAR file and EXE file which I just converted from JAR.

I have put the JAR and EXE together on my website FTP server.

I was wondering if I can read it from the local PC with any

tools(such as HTML, another java file, python or any).

A little bit of description of the JAR or EXE file is:

when it runs on local computer, it gives me a localhost port to access.

So I put something like "localhost:8080" on the web browser for working.

Thank you for your kind advices. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to map a [network drive](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/map-an-ftp-drive-windows)

Basically, you need to mount your ftp server as a drive.

I hope this helps.